# iPhone iOS 4 - schedule app to run functions at specific times and days

Tags: function, ios4, background, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a way to be able to set my app to launch and carry out certain functions depending on the time and day of week. The app needs to be able to set the time and days of week, then run a specific function depending on that time and date. For instance if I set the app to run 1 function 12:00pm every Saturday, and another 3:00pm every Sunday, they can be processed in the background somehow. Essentially I want it to run like a scheduled background, where I might run an incremental backup during the week and a full backup on the weekend.

I've searched all over and can't seem to find any leads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? Also looking for an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Local Notifications:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked into local notifications however it will only notify user with a message, not initiate a function in my app. I'm still digging. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @TedK: Did u get any solution to your problem?