# Schedule app to launch / enter foreground at specific dates / times

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotifications

I would like to have multiple schedules for my app to launch (if possible) or to enter foreground from a suspended state at specific dates / times. It is a type of alarm clock, however I require more than being able to show a notification as this thread suggests.

[iPhone iOS 4 - schedule app to run functions at specific times and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900880/iphone-ios-4-schedule-app-to-run-functions-at-specific-times-and-days)

Is there a way to achieve this, without having the app in the foreground all the time?

I have started reading up on GCD and NS Operations, but not sure whether either will even be applicable.

Answer (score 3):

No, an app can launch or enter the foreground only in response to user intervention, in the following ways:

1. User taps your app icon
2. User opens your app in response to a notification
3. User opens an URL (from a link, or programatically from another app) that opens your app

Comment: While this was true at the time it was written, it is no longer accurate. [iOS now supports a number of background execution modes.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe cannot be done. There are a few tasks that apps are allowed to do while in background mode, such as telephony apps and audio apps. And as you already mentioned, local notifications.

Not sure if this might help, but you can register your app to handle a custom URL scheme. The user could click a specially-crafted URL in an email or web page to open your app.